# Nodejs with ExpressJS including external js code files for use

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

learning NodeJS here... I have this very basic "class" file I put into an external JS file. How do I make this available for all my routing files and or other external js files(that i also like to load) see?

**/classes/music/usermanager.js**

```
function User(){
    this.email = "";
    this.password = "";
    this.userid = "";
}

function UserManager()
{
    this.user = new User();
}

UserManager.prototype.login = new function (email, password){
    var db = new DbManager();
    db.Open();
    params = {
        $email : email,
        $password : password
    }
    db.serialize(function(){
        db.get("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = $email and password =     $password", params, function(err,row) {
        if (!err && row) {
            //log in passed
            this.user.userid = row.user.id;
            this.user.email = row.user.email;
            this.user.password = row.user.password;
            return this.user;
        }
        else if (!err) {
            //log in failed log event
            return null;
        }
        else {
            //error happened through out an event to log the error
            return null;
        }
    });
});
}
```

**/config/strategies/local.strategy.js** example of how I would be using it in another file.

```
var passport = require('passport');
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

module.exports = function () {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    },
    function (email, password, done) {
        //vadliating user here
        var userManager = new UserManager();
        var user = userManager.login(email, password);
        done(null, user);
    }));
};
```

I tried doing something like this in my app.js file and it is barfing on compiling stating "throw new TypeError('app.use() requires middleware functions');".  I could of sworn I read somewhere you could do that but now can't find the resource.

**/asp.js**

```
/*load external js library files for application use*/
app.use ("./classes/music/:path*");
```

Have a feeling i am missing a basic a understanding here still when trying to organize a nodejs/expressjs project.

Comment: You don't need to put `new` before the function when adding a prototype function in your first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actually using the answer in one of your examples. You make modules available by using the `module.exports = whatever;`. Meaning that you can export anything a string, an object, or a "class". So you could export `UserManager` by adding this to the end of the file (or really anywhere).

```
module.exports = UserManager;
```

and require it in another filer by using its relative file path. So if its in the same directory.

```
var UserManager = require('./usermanager.js');
```

So for the local.strategy.js file to require UserManager it would look like: (if you filepaths are all in the same root directory)

```
var UserManager = require('../../classes/music/usermanager.js');
```

Comment: Just adding this here...The other hard part was having the "model" of the user being defined in the same javascript file as the "class" object.  What I wound up doing is the following. 

module.exports  = {
    User : User,
    UserManager : UserManager
}

To have them both accessible when the require was done in another file.

Answer (score 0):

**`/classes/music/usermanager.js`**

```
  // Working for me, try it, hope this may help you

  var model = module.exports; 

   function User() {
    this.email = "";
    this.password = "";
    this.userid = "";  
     }

 function UserManager() {
    this.user = new User();

   }

UserManager.prototype.login = function(email, password) {

      var db = new DbManager();
    db.Open();
    params = {
        $email : email,
        $password : password
    }
    db.serialize(function(){
        db.get("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = $email and password =     $password", params, function(err,row) {
        if (!err && row) {
            //log in passed
            this.user.userid = row.user.id;
            this.user.email = row.user.email;
            this.user.password = row.user.password;
            return this.user;
        }
        else if (!err) {
            //log in failed log event
            return null;
        }
        else {
            //error happened through out an event to log the error
            return null;
        }
    }); 

   });     
   }; 


model.login = function (email, password){    
var usrmng = new UserManager(); 
    return usrmng.login(email, password); 
  };
```

**`/config/strategies/local.strategy.js`**

```
 var usermanager = require('./usermanager'); // path to ur file


  var passport = require('passport');
  LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

  module.exports = function () {
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
   },
  function (email, password, done) {
    //vadliating user here
    //var userManager = new UserManager();
   var use = usermanager.login(email, password);
    done(null, user);
   }));
 };
```